# Sum total values separately of each content in the same column using batch on .csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I made this script bellow:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3,7 delims=;" %%a in (1.csv) do (
  set "a=%%a                           "
  set "b=%%b              "
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%m in ("%%c") do (set "c=     %%m" & set "d= %%n")
  echo !a:~0,22!!b:~0,17!!c!!d:~-10!
))>2.csv
<2.csv set /p header=

(echo %header%
more +1 2.csv |sort /+22) >3.csv


set "NewFile=4.csv"

set "TotalElo=0"
set "TotalMastercard=0"
set "TotalAmericanExpress=0"
set "TotalVisa=0"
set "TotalOther1=0"
set "TotalOther2=0"
set "TotalOther3=0"

for %%I in (3.csv) do (
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=3 delims=" %%A in ("%%I") do (

            set /A TotalElo+=%%A
            set /A TotalMastercard+=%%B
            set /A TotalAmericanExpress+=%%C
            set /A TotalVisa+=%%D
            set /A TotalOther1+=%%E
            set /A TotalOther2+=%%F
            set /A TotalOther3+=%%G

            >>"%NewFile%" echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G


    )
)

>>"%NewFile%" echo Total,%TotalElo%,%TotalAmericanExpress%,%TotalVisa%,%TotalOther1%,%TotalOther2%,%TotalOther3%
move "%NewFile%" "lalala.csv" >nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

I Expected that the my output `lalala.csv` would be like this:

```
Previsão de pagamento Bandeira              Valor líquido
21/05/2019            American Express      R$ 17,95
21/06/2019            American Express      R$ 17,95
13/05/2019            Elo                   R$ 1.415,08
15/05/2019            Elo                   R$ 1.474,79
30/05/2019            Elo                   R$ 100,91
04/09/2019            Elo                   R$ 104,73
08/07/2019            Elo                   R$ 87,31
03/05/2019            Elo                   R$ 950,61
12/09/2019            Mastercard            R$ 100,20
13/08/2019            Mastercard            R$ 100,20
10/06/2019            Mastercard            R$ 104,36
06/05/2019            Mastercard            R$ 129,56
06/06/2019            Mastercard            R$ 136,96
14/10/2019            Mastercard            R$ 151,00
24/06/2019            Visa                  R$ 104,85
14/06/2019            Visa                  R$ 111,01
14/08/2019            Visa                  R$ 111,01
15/07/2019            Visa                  R$ 111,01
16/10/2019            Visa                  R$ 127,29
09/05/2019            Visa                  R$ 15,05
15/08/2019            Visa                  R$ 163,55
16/09/2019            Visa                  R$ 163,55
14/06/2019            Visa                  R$ 90,56

Total VISA: R$ value...
Total ELO:  R$ value...
Total AMERICAN EXPRESS: R$ value...
Total OHTER 1: R$ value...
etc.
```

But my output result is only this: `Total,0,0,0,0,0,0`

I'm not finding the error.

**The informations of this question refers to the other situation contained in this other question:**
[Organize rows, columns and values in a .csv file with batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170712/organize-rows-columns-and-values-in-a-csv-file-with-batch-script)

---

**Edit 1:**

My `3.csv` is that:

```
Previsão de pagamento Bandeira              Valor líquido
21/05/2019            American Express      R$17,95 
21/06/2019            American Express      R$17,95 
13/05/2019            Elo                   R$1.415,08 
30/05/2019            Elo                   R$99.125,91 
04/09/2019            Elo                   R$125.132,73 
05/07/2019            Elo                   R$104,73 
05/08/2019            Elo                   R$104,73 
07/10/2019            Elo                   R$104,73 
04/06/2019            Elo                   R$104,75 
16/05/2019            Elo                   R$109,05 
13/06/2019            Elo                   R$122,05 
14/05/2019            Elo                   R$122,08 
24/07/2019            Elo                   R$129,20 
06/05/2019            Elo                   R$136,09 
23/05/2019            Elo                   R$138,16 
14/08/2019            Elo                   R$139,78 
20/09/2019            Elo                   R$144,02 
21/10/2019            Elo                   R$144,02 
24/05/2019            Elo                   R$159,20 
11/06/2019            Elo                   R$16,55 
10/05/2019            Elo                   R$164,37 
14/06/2019            Elo                   R$168,82 
20/08/2019            Elo                   R$183,85 
16/09/2019            Elo                   R$197,34 
15/07/2019            Elo                   R$199,75 
12/07/2019            Elo                   R$208,71 
23/05/2019            Elo                   R$214,40 
06/05/2019            Elo                   R$22,42 
07/05/2019            Elo                   R$233,96 
20/05/2019            Elo                   R$238,07 
19/07/2019            Elo                   R$25,13 
19/08/2019            Elo                   R$25,13 
09/05/2019            Elo                   R$25,39 
02/08/2019            Elo                   R$25,80 
03/07/2019            Elo                   R$25,80 
22/07/2019            Elo                   R$253,45 
02/05/2019            Elo                   R$28,00 
31/05/2019            Elo                   R$28,00 
31/07/2019            Elo                   R$28,00 
21/06/2019            Elo                   R$292,31 
21/05/2019            Elo                   R$292,34 
24/06/2019            Elo                   R$297,30 
14/05/2019            Elo                   R$306,36 
10/05/2019            Elo                   R$307,12 
13/05/2019            Elo                   R$327,45 
17/06/2019            Elo                   R$337,36 
11/06/2019            Elo                   R$345,08 
08/05/2019            Elo                   R$353,11 
24/10/2019            Elo                   R$36,06 
10/06/2019            Elo                   R$39,06 
26/06/2019            Elo                   R$40,50 
27/05/2019            Elo                   R$40,50 
29/07/2019            Elo                   R$40,50 
10/06/2019            Elo                   R$407,22 
16/05/2019            Elo                   R$439,53 
27/06/2019            Elo                   R$46,42 
28/05/2019            Elo                   R$46,42 
09/05/2019            Elo                   R$462,10 
06/05/2019            Elo                   R$472,44 
17/05/2019            Elo                   R$472,48 
09/08/2019            Elo                   R$51,65 
09/09/2019            Elo                   R$51,65 
10/07/2019            Elo                   R$51,65 
10/10/2019            Elo                   R$51,65 
04/07/2019            Elo                   R$53,81 
12/06/2019            Elo                   R$55,50 
15/05/2019            Elo                   R$57,08 
16/08/2019            Elo                   R$57,56 
02/05/2019            Elo                   R$588,24 
29/08/2019            Elo                   R$59,25 
30/07/2019            Elo                   R$59,25 
30/09/2019            Elo                   R$59,25 
13/08/2019            Elo                   R$59,97 
23/07/2019            Elo                   R$60,29 
16/07/2019            Elo                   R$65,16 
19/06/2019            Elo                   R$67,42 
18/06/2019            Elo                   R$68,64 
11/09/2019            Elo                   R$73,14 
12/08/2019            Elo                   R$73,14 
14/10/2019            Elo                   R$73,14 
11/07/2019            Elo                   R$74,71 
13/05/2019            Elo                   R$75,19 
17/07/2019            Elo                   R$76,91 
03/06/2019            Elo                   R$79,62 
05/06/2019            Elo                   R$82,27 
23/08/2019            Elo                   R$86,70 
23/09/2019            Elo                   R$86,70 
01/07/2019            Elo                   R$87,25 
06/06/2019            Elo                   R$87,31 
07/05/2019            Elo                   R$87,31 
08/07/2019            Elo                   R$87,31 
03/05/2019            Elo                   R$950,61 
15/05/2019            Elo                   R$99.474,79 
12/09/2019            Mastercard            R$100,20 
13/08/2019            Mastercard            R$100,20 
10/06/2019            Mastercard            R$104,36 
06/05/2019            Mastercard            R$129,56 
06/06/2019            Mastercard            R$136,96 
14/10/2019            Mastercard            R$151,00 
12/06/2019            Mastercard            R$17,96 
11/06/2019            Mastercard            R$24,14 
15/05/2019            Mastercard            R$306,89 
19/06/2019            Mastercard            R$31,16 
20/05/2019            Mastercard            R$31,16 
22/07/2019            Mastercard            R$32,23 
14/06/2019            Mastercard            R$374,27 
13/06/2019            Mastercard            R$38,71 
14/05/2019            Mastercard            R$38,71 
04/06/2019            Mastercard            R$39,06 
15/07/2019            Mastercard            R$425,07 
13/09/2019            Mastercard            R$50,80 
14/08/2019            Mastercard            R$50,80 
17/06/2019            Mastercard            R$50,82 
10/05/2019            Mastercard            R$61,36 
24/06/2019            Mastercard            R$64,60 
23/05/2019            Mastercard            R$64,62 
21/05/2019            Mastercard            R$70,57 
21/06/2019            Mastercard            R$70,57 
13/05/2019            Mastercard            R$80,40 
13/05/2019            Mastercard            R$84,56 
10/06/2019            Mastercard            R$99,66 
08/05/2019            Mastercard            R$99.324,18 
24/06/2019            Visa                  R$104,85 
14/06/2019            Visa                  R$111,01 
14/08/2019            Visa                  R$111,01 
15/07/2019            Visa                  R$111,01 
16/10/2019            Visa                  R$127,29 
09/05/2019            Visa                  R$15,05 
15/08/2019            Visa                  R$163,55 
16/09/2019            Visa                  R$163,55 
09/08/2019            Visa                  R$19,26 
09/09/2019            Visa                  R$19,26 
10/05/2019            Visa                  R$19,26 
10/07/2019            Visa                  R$19,26 
16/07/2019            Visa                  R$194,36 
17/06/2019            Visa                  R$194,42 
06/05/2019            Visa                  R$254,65 
29/05/2019            Visa                  R$33,85 
10/06/2019            Visa                  R$34,31 
10/05/2019            Visa                  R$344,33 
19/06/2019            Visa                  R$36,81 
19/08/2019            Visa                  R$36,81 
22/07/2019            Visa                  R$36,81 
23/05/2019            Visa                  R$41,09 
23/07/2019            Visa                  R$41,09 
21/06/2019            Visa                  R$48,95 
22/05/2019            Visa                  R$48,95 
16/05/2019            Visa                  R$49,08 
15/05/2019            Visa                  R$58,83 
27/05/2019            Visa                  R$63,76 
20/05/2019            Visa                  R$64,19 
27/06/2019            Visa                  R$65,31 
28/05/2019            Visa                  R$65,31 
13/06/2019            Visa                  R$82,88 
14/05/2019            Visa                  R$82,88 
13/05/2019            Visa                  R$88,30 
14/06/2019            Visa                  R$90,56
```

Comment: You don't have a third token. When you set `delims` to nothing, the whole line will be in `token 1`.

Comment: @Stephan But i have 3 columns(3 token, not?). So i just tried to skip the first line and got the whole values of the third column. I'm still learning batch enconding, sorry if my mind is wrong.

Comment: No, you don't. If you use spaces as delimiters (nothing else available), then `American Express` will ruin your day (because it's two words)

Comment: Also, `cmd` (`set /a` to be exact) can only handle Integer (`INT32` to be exact), so "just adding" doesn't work.

Comment: You have to remove the commas (`17,95` -> `1795`), add those values and re-insert the comma to the sum (and hope, the numbers don't get too big)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard please check my `Edit 1`.
@Stephan Good point! So how can i put(for example) a `_` in all names with space? for example `American_Express` `Good_Card` etc.?

Comment: That would work. Note: `R$` and `17,95` are *two* tokens (if you use SPACE as delimiter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of tricks are neccessary to do that in pure batch (reasons: DataStructure and the fact we can only handle `INT32` numbers)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (3.csv) do ( 
  set "line=%%a"
  set "card=!line:~22,20!"
  set "value=!line:~46!"
  set "value=!value:,=!"
  set "value=!value:.=!"
  set /a _!card: =! += !value!
)
>4.csv (
  type 3.csv
  echo(
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_=" %%a in ('set _') do (
    set /a GrandTotal+=%%b
    call :formatvalue %%b
    echo Total %%a: !sum!
  )
echo(
call :formatvalue !GrandTotal!
echo Grand Total: !sum!
)
goto  :eof

:formatvalue
set "sum=    %1"
set "sum=%sum:~0,-2%,%sum:~-2%"
if not "%sum:~-7,1%" == " " set "sum=    %sum:~0,-6%.%sum:~-6%"
if not "%sum:~-11,1%" == " " set "sum=    %sum:~0,-10%.%sum:~-10%"
if not "%sum:~-15,1%" == " " set "sum=%sum:~0,-14%.%sum:~-14%"
set "sum=%sum: =%"
goto :eof
```

Output (`4.csv`)

```
...

Total AmericanExpress: 35,90
Total Elo: 338.225,03
Total Mastercard: 102.154,58
Total Visa: 3.041,89

Grand Total: 443.457,40
```

First `for` loop to extract the data and add the values for the different card types.
Second `for` to reformat and show the sums.

In the process, we loose spaces in the card names (`American Express`-->`AmericanExpress`, and the cards are sorted alphabetical, but I guess, you can live with that.

**Edit**
just an extended stand-alone "debug version" of the subroutine to show step by step, what exactly happens:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

call :formatvalue 123456789
echo Result: %sum%
goto  :eof

:formatvalue
set "sum=    %1"
echo step 0 sum="%sum%"

echo step 1 sum="%sum%", sub1="%sum:~0,-2%", sub2="%sum:~-2%"
set "sum=%sum:~0,-2%,%sum:~-2%"
echo step 2 sum="%sum%"

echo teststring 1="%sum:~-7,1%"; sub1="%sum:~0,-6%" ; sub2="%sum:~-6%"
if not "%sum:~-7,1%" == " " set "sum=    %sum:~0,-6%.%sum:~-6%"
echo step 3 sum="%sum%"

echo teststring 2="%sum:~-11,1%"; sub1="%sum:~0,-10%" ; sub2="%sum:~-10%"
if not "%sum:~-11,1%" == " " set "sum=    %sum:~0,-10%.%sum:~-10%"
echo step 4 sum="%sum%"

echo teststring 3="%sum:~-15,1%"; sub1="%sum:~0,-14%" ; sub2="%sum:~-14%"
if not "%sum:~-15,1%" == " " set "sum=%sum:~0,-14%.%sum:~-14%"
echo step 5 sum="%sum%"

set "sum=%sum: =%"
echo step 6 sum="%sum%"

goto :eof
```

This should help you to understand the substring manipulation. Try also `call :formatvalue 123` or even `call :formatvalue abcdefghi` (works exactly the same, becaues it's only strings - `cmd` knows nothing about numbers (except a limited Integer processing by `set /a`))

You say, your `3.csv` is ever changing, so you need to understand to be able to adapt the script.

Just to note: elzooilogico's routine `:makeNumberReadable` is more elegant (from a programmers perspective) and probably a bit faster (didn't try), but at your current level of understanding I wouldn't even try to explain it to you - no offense intended .

Comment: Nice! I just altered this line `set "sum=!sum:~-8,-5!.!sum:~-5,-2!,!sum:~-2!"` to put the `.`. But there's two problemns: 1) I can't have values above `R$ 99.999,99` and the 2) `R$ .35,90` (It occurs with cheap values under 3 decimals. Can you help me?

Comment: added a few lines to reformat the numbers with thousands delimiters (Phew...)

Comment: @stephan I've posted an answer (not a really one) to reformat the total to human readable form in a differeent way. your solution is neat, it's only other point of view.

Comment: @Stephan Sorry i didn't get the logic of all these lines(after 2 hours trying) `if not "!sum:~-7,1!" == " " set "sum=    !sum:~0,-6!.!sum:~-6!"`. And i realizes the if the value is `R$ 99.999,99` it doesn't sumn. Now it's summing until `R$ 9.999,99`. The most i get for the `GRAND VALUE` was that `!GrandTotal:~0,-5!.!GrandTotal:~-5,-2!,!GrandTotal:~-2!`

Comment: @elzooilogico Thank you! I'll see it better later.

Comment: @I'mNotHere: [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) should enlighten you.

Comment: @Stephan i read it. But i didn't get the logic. Just tried with `9.999.999` and count these carachteres based in your conditions, but i didn't get the logic. Eg.:      `if not "!sum:~-7,1!" == " " set "sum=    !sum:~0,-6!.!sum:~-6!"`. It means `if not 9.999.999` extracting only one `9` the sum will be `9.999999` ? Can you explain me plase?

Comment: `if not "!sum:~-7,1!" == " "` = "if the seventh char from the right is not a space" (remember: we don't work with numbers but with strings! So the comma counts too). The `set` command then inserts a dot (split the string into "from start to last-but-six" and "last six" and put a dot between)

Comment: @Stephan It's hard! `set "sum=!sum:~0,-2!,!sum:~-2!"` this is not wrong? for example: `17,95` it will extract `17,` and then `95` = `17,,95`.
Second: `if not "!sum:~-7,1!" == " " set "sum=    !sum:~0,-6!.!sum:~-6!"`. It means that `9.999,99` it will extract `9.` then `999,99` = `9..999,99` ? I'm really lost on it, because i realized that anyway it isn't summing right the cards. For example: `AmericanExpress has 2 times R$17,95` and it summed only `R$15,95`. Just update my `3.csv`. Please read it.

Comment: When I do `set "sum=!sum:~0,-2!,!sum:~-2!"`, there is no comma in `sum`. We are working with the string `1795`, not with the number `17,95`. Second: no, it will extract one character only (the seventh from the right). See how I added spaces at the beginning of the string in the lines before? If the 7th from right is a space, then it's not a number, that means the string is too short to insert another dot. The sums were correct with the data as it was with my answer (doublechecked with Excel). Will check the rest another time - have to leave now.

Comment: you changed the format of `3.csv` (again...). Let me check.

Comment: adapted for new `3.csv` format - and outsourced number formatting to a subroutine for cleaner code.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, my `3.csv` will always change, but will work only with this way. So i guess it's fine now. Thank you for your time and your explaning. Unfortunatelly i still didn't understand `if not "!sum:~-7,1!" == " " set "sum=    !sum:~0,-6!.!sum:~-6!"` (understood the command but not how it is working there). I'm begginer in batch script. Thanks a lot for your help. It will be very useful! You are awsome!

Answer (score 3):

> **This is not an answer**, it's a follow up of Stephan's one, but I cannot edit     nor include this as a comment... for the sake of remove limitations (though, yes, more complex code, please see [Macros with parameters appended](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518))

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:: see http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518
set ^"LF=^

^" don't remove previous line     & rem newline
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"  & rem newline with line continuation

:: get string length
set STRLEN=for %%{ in (1 2) do if %%{==2 (%\n%
  for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%1 in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
    set "S=A!%%~2!"^&set "L=0"%\n%
    for /L %%A in (12,-1,0) do (set/a "L|=1<<%%A"^&for %%B in (!L!) do if "!S:~%%B,1!"=="" set/a "L&=~1<<%%A")%\n%
    for /F "delims=" %%} in ("!L!") do EndLocal^& set "%%1=%%~}"%\n%
  )%\n%
) else SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=,
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a "len=0, maxLen=0"

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (3.csv) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "card=!line:~22,20!"
  set "value=!line:~47!"
  set "value=!value:,=!"
  set "value=!value:.=!"
  set /a _!card: =! += !value!, GrandTotal+=!value!
  set "line=!line:~0,47!!value!"
  %STRLEN% len,line
  if !len! GTR !maxLen! set/a maxLen=!len!
)

set "padding=------------------------------------------------------------"

(
  type 3.csv & echo(
  echo(!padding:~0,%maxLen%!
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_=" %%a in ('set _') do (
    set "sum=%%b"
    call :makeCurrencyReadable "Total %%a: ", "%%b", sum
    echo !sum!
  )
  echo(!padding:~0,%maxLen%!
  call :makeCurrencyReadable "GRAND TOTAL: ", "!GrandTotal!", GrandTotal
  echo !GrandTotal!
) >5.csv

EndLocal
EndLocal
exit/B

::these two may be also be macros (but I'm too lazy today)
:makeCurrencyReadable header, value, variable
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str="
set "header=%~1" & set "padding=                                                            "
set/a "len=0, lenN=0, pad=20, maxTitle=maxLen-(pad+1)"
call :makeNumberReadable "%~2", str, lenN
%STRLEN% lenN,str
set /a "lenN=pad-lenN"
set "header=!header!!padding!"
set "str=!header:~0,%maxTitle%!!padding:~0,%lenN%!!str!"
EndLocal & set "%3=%str%"

:makeNumberReadable value, variable
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "res=%~1"
set "str=!res:~0,-2!" & set "dec=!res:~-2!" & set "res="
set/a "len=0, current=0, now=0, dot=0"
%STRLEN% len,str
set/a len-=1
for /L %%i in (%len%,-1,0) do (
    set /A "current+=1, now=current%%3"
    if !dot! EQU 1 (set "res=.!res!" & set/a "dot=0")
    set "res=!str:~%%i,1!!res!"
    if !now! EQU 0 (set /A "dot=1")
)
EndLocal & set "%2=%res%,%dec%"
goto:eof
```

Comment: I like your `:makeNumberReadable`. More code, but more universal.

Comment: @stephan thanks, still not universal. it may discover decimals or not, and also use it as macro to speed it up. more also, what about comma and dot separators? not the same if you are latin or saxon speaker. I likedvery much your way of storing sums in vars!

Comment: @elzooilogico Thank you!